# Create CMD Batch file for WMIC

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I want to write this line from CMD so I can execute it in a batch file on a remote computer on a network that I can't remote into.

/>wmic

/>/output:C:\InstallList.txt product get name,version

Answer (score 1):

you don't have to use `wmic` interactively:

```
wmic /output:C:\InstallList.txt product get name,version
```

or simply:

```
wmic product get name,version >C:\InstallList.txt
```

Comment: Well actually I need to change that.
I need it to get the info of a drive from a network location:
\\192.168.1.42\c$

Comment: @ChrisZog have you tried `wmic /node:servername product get, name,verison`?